# Keyboard Shortcut for Default project dropdown in Package Manager Console?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, nuget

I have assigned a keyboard shortcut for opening the Package Manager Console.  I can use Shift+ESC to close the console.  However, I cannot seem to find any way to use the keyboard to change the default project.  (*Tab does not do it*)
Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Alt + T, N, O** opens Package manager

**Alt + J** puts focus on Default Project dropdown

Comment: How did you find the ALT-J shortcut?  It doesn't show up in Options | Keyboard | "Press shortcut keys"?

Comment: Seems that ALT-K gives the "package source" dropdown - only discovered by experimentation...

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy Press Alt and the relevant shortcut key is underlined. Shift Alt J also does same as Alt J (this same approach works in other tool windows such as the Output window too - the Shift is only necessary where there is a clashing main menu Alt Key combo)